# CXF JAX-RS Service - HATEOAS

Tags: cxf, hateoas

I am looking to add HATEOAS functionality to an existing Rest web service.
JAX-RS is using the CXF, and we do want to change that. I have seen SPRING-HATEOAS over the net, to implement HATEOAS but it is not for CXF application. Any help in this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To mix them, you could look at CXF interceptors: just call the Spring Link provider with an outinterceptor that add your provided links to the message.

If you succeed, in interested in it (I wanted to do it in my spare time).

There are some other alternatives (that a less complete as spring Hateoas I think) in this mailing list discussion: http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/CXF-with-HATEOS-or-hypermedia-td4347138.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am using the URIInfo and Builder classes to create the links and sending them as part of the response resource.I will look at this too.